# iOS - Get text from 10 UITextViews with the same name

Tags: ios, nsarray, uitextview

I have 10 `UITextViews` that contains different text but they all had the same name, when I tried to `NSLog` the `txtview.text` it showed me the text of the last `UITextView` only but I want to get the text of all `UITextViews` into NSArray, is there's any way to make this works?

Comment: Bye "all had the same name", do you mean that you reused the variable name when declaring them, e.g.

`UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; // text view #2...`

?

If so, then you need to declare an `NSArray` to hold those 10 textview instances.

Comment: @NRitH yes I mean the variable name. how to `NSArray` to hold textview instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set tags on your `UITextView` and then recover it by using:

```
UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
```

and then add it to your array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:textView, nil];
```